# Scrolling a ListView and a ListFragment of a TabHost simultaneously

Tags: android, listview, scroll, android-tabhost, android-listfragment

As the ridiculously long title would suggest this is a complicated problem to explain so here's an illustration:

[image: poorly-drawn layout]

**General:** What I have designed is a FragmentActivity that contains a ListView and a TabHost. The TabHost contains 3 tabs in the form of ListFragment.

**RED column:** This is my ListView that resides in the FragmentActivity layout and class.

**GREEN column:** The TabHost that resides in the same FragmentActivity and layout as the ListView, and contains 3 ListFragment classes, each with its own layout.

**What I want to accomplish:** When I touch and scroll (fling) one of the lists (either the RED or GREEN column), I want all the others to move at the same time. So when I scroll the RED column, the **current** GREEN one will scroll simultaneously when RED is touched and moreover the other tabs will go at the same position with it. I want it to feel like one united List with the left column fixed when changing tabs (horizontal scrolling on GREEN column).

**Class sum up:**

- MainFragmentActivity : contains the ListView and TabHost
- ListFragment1
- ListFragment2 : they are separate classes that are contained in the TabHost as tabs
- ListFragment3

**Layout sum up:**

- main_fragment_activity
- tab1_fragment
- tab2_fragment
- tab3_fragment

Sorry for long post and title. I just wanted to clarify my question.